# mssql вывести столбец в одну строку

Tags: sql

Microsoft SQL Server 2012
Нужно вывести значения столбца в строки через запятую с группировкой по значению в другом столбце.

[image: Пример]

Comment: зуб дам, что вопрос на применение функции PIVOT, но по Вашему вопросу точнее ответить не получается :-(

Comment: [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Akina - ТОчно! А то я уже голову сломал...  Спасибо! Правда, в 2012-м SQL может еще не быть STRING_AGG, но она "эмулируется" через FOR_XML

Comment: STRING_AGG c SQL Server 2017

Comment: Старый SQL Server? тогда стандартно - через `SELECT .. FOR XML PATH('')`.

Comment: Да, уже пытаюсь через FOR XML PATH(''). Но пока не сообразила как именно. Спасибо

Comment: Вот здесь http://www.sqlbooks.ru/Articles02/programmingmssql02_ru.htm похожий пример, но как туда засунуть GROUP BY - ума не приложу

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id CHAR(1), val INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 3), ('B', 4);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> :- | --:
> A  |   1
> A  |   2
> B  |   3
> B  |   4
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id,
>        STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(val AS VARCHAR)
>               FROM test t2
>               WHERE t1.id = t2.id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') vals
> FROM test t1
> GROUP BY id;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | vals
> :- | :---
> A  | 1,2 
> B  | 3,4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6d02a4955458cd2a90307feea1a04730)*

Answer (score 1):

Со STRING_AGG вроде всё просто:

```
    SELECT Id, Name FROM Table_1 

    Id  Name
    1   А         
    2   А         
    3   Б         
    4   Б
```

Тогда

```
    SELECT Name, STRING_AGG(Id,', ')  AS Result FROM Table_1 GROUP BY Name
```

даёт нам

```
    Name    Result
    А           1, 2
    Б           3, 4
```

Насчет `FOR XML PATH('')` - мучаюсь уже минут 20, готов уже сдаться